# Oil in power steering

Tags: honda, overheating, radiator, odyssey, oil-in-coolant

If someone put oil in my radiator and in my power steering, how long before the car would overheat? I had an oil change on 11/19 and no one else has done anything to the car except put gas in the gas tank and washer fluid in the washer fluid reservoir (that was me). The only people that have been under the hood are the people that change my oil. On Christmas night I drove home from work fine and then when I got home it started overheating. My husband opened the hood and had to flush out the radiator bc there was hot oil in it. Then found out there was also oil in my power steering. I lock my car and the only way under the hood is by releasing it inside the car. 2016 Honda Odyssey.

Comment: Power steering usually has oil in it - and it is usually a reddish color.

Comment: Oil is a lot more expensive than water - I've a doubt that someone would have filled your cooling system with oil willingly?

Comment: The power steering reservoir should have oil in it, power steering fluid is a type of oil and i doubt that you could tell visually if some had been added unless it was a significant amount. The oil in the radiator is more concerning.  Unless you're sure that someone put oil in there, the most common cause is a leaking head gasket, a warped cylinder head, or a cracked engine block.  If oil is moving from the engine to the cooling system, you should see the oil level dropping too.

Comment: This sounds like a blown head gasket to me, this allows water into your oil and oil into your water. Check your oil, if it's foamy then you unfortunately have a serious problem.

Comment: A blown head gasket would also explain the overheating.